# Is it a correct word about mathematical problems

Tags: mathematics

Is the following word correct?

---

Question) x = 3y, y = 4t

**Considering the equations above, represent x with respect to t.**

---

Answer) x = 12t

---

Is the bold sentence correct?

Comment: It could be written several different ways.  I can't see anything wrong with the above, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the norm is to write something like "express x **in terms of** t".

Answer (score 2):

You can simply say

```
Solve x with respect to t.
```

Alternatively, I have seen this kind of question commonly formatted in the following way:

```
Question) 

Considering the equations

    x = 3y
    y = 4t

Solve x with respect to t
```